# XSD-generated class doesn't include XInclude content after deserialization

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, xsd.exe, xinclude

I'm using the XmlSerializer class to deserialize a XSD.exe-generated class from an XML document.  The XML document has two XInclude tags to other XML documents.  After deserialization, the XInclude content is missing.

Does anyone know if the .NET XML parsers handle XInclude content?  IF not, any suggested workarounds?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use subscribe to XmlSerializer.UnknownElement and load additional document yourself. In fact you are on the way to implement XInclude for .NET. Please, consider publishing NUGET package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XInclude is not supported by .NET.

Comment: Says who? Could you cite this properly?

Comment: @dan there used to be an article called something like "XML technologies supported in .NET). XInclude has never been on that list.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Do you happen to know anything about [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4972)? The "project homepage" it links to is dead.

Comment: @dan it looks old and dead and supported by a single developer, if at all. I recommend sticking with whatever Microsoft or a major vendor supports. Here's the Microsoft list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256177.aspx

Comment: @dan the other XML implementation is point you at is Saxon, at http://www.saxonica.com/products/products.xml. it also doesn't support XInclude.

Comment: @JohnSaunders That's unfortunate, but thank you for the advice and resources!